# How to remove Chutzpah from project to not show result in test explorer?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, chutzpah

How to remove Chutzpah from project to not show result in test explorer?

I have made a demo project to learn Chutzpah and installed it for VS2013. Now in my another project I don't use Chutzpah but Karma for testing Angularjs test cases, but still test Explorer shows Angularjs unit tests as failed tests, how can i remove angularjs test cases from test explorer? I only want backend Csharp Unit tests to run in test explorer.

Please help me soon...

Answer (score 3):

You may need to uninstall the **Chutzpah Test Runner** and **Chutzpah Test Adapter** Extensions from visual stuido. You can do this by going to **Tools** => **Extensions & Updates**.

Comment: sorry its late, couldnt back since long..but i have tried that already but its not worked for me , but finally i have completely uninstall and reinstall VS 2013 and then its  solved, thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: you may need to restart your visual studio..it worked for me.